# How to show multiple Dictionary items in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, listbox

My code has two ListBoxes (`LeftListBox` and `RightListBox`) and one TextBox. Those ListBoxes transfer the items between the them. The TextBox shows a number, which corresponds to the SelectedItem in `RightListBox` (e.g., when `T1` is selected, it shows `10`, when `T2` is selected, it shows `20`, and so on).

I've just made it!! ... but those ListBoxes show **only the 1st Dictionary item** out of three ... How can I show all of them?

[image]

Here is my code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxMoveAll.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxMoveAll"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="LeftListBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LeftListBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"
            SelectionMode="Extended" Margin="0,10"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Add" x:Name="Add_Button" Click="Add_Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Remove" x:Name="Remove_Button" Click="Remove_Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="RightListBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding RightListBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"
            SelectionMode="Extended" Margin="0,10"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="0,10">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue.Step, ElementName=RightListBox}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using ListBoxMoveAll.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace ListBoxMoveAll
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, Graph>> LeftListBoxItems { get; } 
            = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, Graph>>();
        public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, Graph>> RightListBoxItems { get; } 
            = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, Graph>>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Dictionary<string, Graph> Dic = new Dictionary<string, Graph>();
            Dic.Add("T1", new Graph(10));
            Dic.Add("T2", new Graph(20));
            Dic.Add("T3", new Graph(30));

            LeftListBoxItems.Add(Dic);

            // Yes! There are three items in Dic!
            foreach (var item in Dic)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Add_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //foreach (TestModel item in LeftListBox.SelectedItems.OfType<TestModel>().ToList())
            foreach (Dictionary<string, Graph> item 
                in LeftListBox.SelectedItems.OfType<Dictionary<string, Graph>>().ToList())
            {
                LeftListBoxItems.Remove(item);
                RightListBoxItems.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private void Remove_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Dictionary<string, Graph> item 
                in RightListBox.SelectedItems.OfType<Dictionary<string, Graph>>().ToList())
            {
                RightListBoxItems.Remove(item);
                LeftListBoxItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model/Graph.cs

```
namespace ListBoxMoveAll.Model
{
    public class Graph
    {
        public Graph(int step) { Step = step; }

        public int Step { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Since the foreach statement shows that there are three items in Dic, I think my XAML has an issue, but I cannot figure that out. You guys might know what the issue is. Sorry if this is a very basic question ... Thank you in advance.

**New Discovery:** I've added another foreach statement for `LeftListBoxItems`:

```
foreach (var item in LeftListBoxItems)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
            }
```

... The output is **only once** and the content is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,ListBoxMoveAll.Model.Graph]
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using data binding the "proper" way to handle this is to wrap both the text and item in a view model:

```
public class GraphViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; }
    public Graph Graph { get; }

    public GraphViewModel(string text, Graph graph) => (Text, Graph) = (text, graph);
}
```

No need for the dictionary, your collections can use this type instead:

```
    public ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel> LeftListBoxItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel> RightListBoxItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>();
```

Similarly, there's no point in adding items to a dictionary only to add them to the collection immediately afterwards, just add them to the collection directly:

```
LeftListBoxItems.Add(new GraphViewModel("T1", new Graph(10)));
LeftListBoxItems.Add(new GraphViewModel("T2", new Graph(20)));
LeftListBoxItems.Add(new GraphViewModel("T3", new Graph(30)));
```

A minor change to each of your button handlers:

```
foreach (var item in LeftListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<GraphViewModel>().ToList())
... and ...
foreach (var item in RightListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<GraphViewModel>().ToList())
```

Finally, bind your list box `DisplayMemberPath` properties to `Text` and get rid of the `SelectedValuePath`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LeftListBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding LeftListBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    SelectionMode="Extended" Margin="0,10"/>

<ListBox x:Name="RightListBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding RightListBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    SelectionMode="Extended" Margin="0,10"/>
```

This is similar to Genos Loser's 2nd example, but a view model is more typesafe than a KeyValuePair and it's also easier to add INPC to later if you need to.

Comment: Now it works! I had to change the TextBox Binding to `<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue.Graph.Step, ElementName=RightListBox}"/>`, though. Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the LeftListBoxItems only has one item when initializing the MainWindow's constructor, so only shows one item is normal.

So the problem is you should put 3 items in the LeftListBoxItems, not just only once( LeftListBoxItems.Add(Dic); ).

If you want to resolve the problem, perhaps you can change the

```
ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, Graph>>
```

to

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, Graph>>
```

, so that you can show 3 items on the app.

### Updated

If you want to keep Dictionary type as your collection property, you can refer this link [WPF - How can I implement an ObservableCollection<K,T> with a key (like a Dictionary)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818365/wpf-how-can-i-implement-an-observablecollectionk-t-with-a-key-like-a-dictio) to change ObservableCollection type.

Comment: Thank you, but how far should I change from `Dictionary<string, Graph>` to `KeyValuePair<string, Graph>`? All of them? Then, I got a `CS1061: 'KeyValuePair<string, Graph>' does not contain a definition for 'Add'` error at `Dic.Add("T1", new Graph(10));`. Do you know how to fix this?